# Sequelize, MySQL - Filtering rows in table with JSON column values

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, sequelize.js

Need help in figuring out how to filter rows in MySQL table's JSON column with nested values using Sequelize. Documentation doesn't have it (Only given for PostgreSQL & MSSQL - [ref](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#json))

Table definition -

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Comment = sequelize.define('Comment', {
    action: DataTypes.STRING,
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    reason: DataTypes.STRING,
    reference: DataTypes.JSON,
    active: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 1,
    },
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        Comment.belongsTo(models.User, {
          foreignKey: 'userId',
        });
      },
    },
  });
  return Comment;
};
```

Values of reference column in `Comments` table -

```
{
  "orderItemId": 2,
  "xkey": 3,
  "ykey": 4
}
{
  "orderItemId": 4,
  "xkey": 1,
  "ykey": 1
}
{
  "orderItemId": 3,
  "xkey": 1,
  "ykey": 6
}
{
  "orderItemId": 2,
  "xkey": 1,
  "ykey": 0
}
```

How do I filter all the rows where "orderItemId" is 2.

Expected SQL query

```
select * from Comments where reference->"$.orderItemId" = 2
```

Figured out a way using `sequelize.literal`, but is there a way of not using this function.

```
models.Comment.findAll({
  where: sequelize.literal(`reference->"$.orderItemId"=2`),
})
```

How to add multiple conditions in the above case like -

`reference->"$.orderItemId" = 2 and action = 'xyz'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Need to use `Sequelize.Op`

Example:

```
models.Comment.findAll({
    where: {
        action: 'xyz',
        [Op.and]: sequelize.literal(`reference->"$.orderItemId"=2`),
    },
});
```

[Sequelize (Operators)](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly. Also, anyway to remove the use of literal?

Comment: Can be used sequelize.col 
 sequelize.where(sequelize.col('profile->user.first_name'), {
                    [Op.like]: sequelizeFilters.search,
                }),

Comment: Did you like my answer? If so, rate it.

Comment: This worked perfectly for object, but how with array object? for example:

[{"status": "y", "user_id": 6}, {"status": "n", "user_id": 3}]

I've try with code above did't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use with below.

```js
Comment.findAll({
  action:'xys',
  'reference.orderItemid':2
})

// oR

Comment.findAll({
  action:'xys',
  reference:{
  orderItemId:2
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Try this:-

```
reference: {
              [Op.and]: [{orderItemId: {[Op.eq]: 2}}]
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on the answer provided by [Uladzislau Vavilau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52290602/2730233), the following works to filter rows in a table where the value of a JSON property is within an array of values, and not just one value:

```
const orderItemIdsArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]

models.Comment.findAll({
    where: {
        action: 'xyz',
        [Op.and] = [
            sequelize.literal(`reference->"$.orderItemId" IN (${orderItemIdsArray})`)
        ]
```

If the ids are UUID (string), you will need to enclose them with quotes before doing that:

```
const orderItemIdsArray = [
    "3ad108a4-f68c-4aca-9967-072ce5ec21af", 
    "ef30f7ca-b1bb-4e94-a06f-b6c783f5dc1f", 
    "bb591f28-0df9-4254-aa9b-c162fb0ed154"
]

const idsWithQuotes = orderItemIdsArray.map((id) => '"' + id + '"')

models.Comment.findAll({
    where: {
        action: 'xyz',
        [Op.and] = [
            sequelize.literal(`reference->"$.orderItemId" IN (${idsWithQuotes})`)
        ]
```

Comment: It seems like this would open you up to injection attacks.  Never directly insert a variable into a query clause.

Comment: @KimballRobinson this code isn't inserting anything. It's using an array to filter the data. 
It is assumed that your data (in this case, the array of ids) is already sanitized.