# How to call a Sequelize MySQL JSON query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have a User model that includes a json data type. I'm using MySQL as my database, but when looking through their documentation for how to query using JSON, there appears to be nothing on MySQL.

```
const User = db.define("User", {
  UserId: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  colors: {
    type: Sequelize.JSON,
    allowNull: false
  }
}
```

I have Users that have an id, and an array with their favorite colors in it.

```
UserId    | colors
    1     |["black, "blue"]
    2     |["blue"]
    3     |["black"]
```

I want to query for all users that have the favorite color blue. I tried querying like this,

```
User.findAll({ where: {colors: ["blue"]} })
```

and expected to be returned users 1 and 2, but this doesn't work and I have not found any sources online that shows what to do. Some stackoverflows have solutions for JSON objects, like this [Sequelize, MySQL - Filtering rows in table with JSON column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290123/sequelize-mysql-filtering-rows-in-table-with-json-column-values), but I can't find any sources for arrays. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sequelize.fn` and `sequelize.col` methods to specify an SQL function call and a table column, respectively. This way you can create your own where condition.

```
User.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('JSON_CONTAINS', sequelize.col('colors'), sequelize.literal('blue'), sequelize.literal('$')), 1)
});
```

It corresponds to below mysql query:

```
// SELECT * FROM Users WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(colors, 'blue', '$') = 1;
```

Comment: I'm giving this a try, and I'm receiving this error, Error: Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 0, any idea as to why?

Comment: updated the answer, try once. error seems like it's not taking as string

Comment: The reference link: https://sequelize.org/v6/manual/other-data-types.html#mssql

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be:

```
User.findAll({
      where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('JSON_CONTAINS', sequelize.literal('colors'), '"blue"', '$'), 1)
});
```

Note:

- The 2nd parameter of JSON_CONTAINS should be string.
- Because the data of question is an array of string, so we need to add a " for searching keyword (e.g: "blue").